# Why my debug do not have the update classes and resources option?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, server

My debug options is below, but my facet do not have the

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Do you use exploded artifact?

Answer (score 0):

Because your Artifacts is not the explored.
Config a explored Artifacts:

1.Goto your Project Structures:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

2.Then you create a Web Application: Explored

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

3.Then you should in Edit Configurations...-> Deployment

Redeploy the explored Artifact.